# python pandas deepdiff two yaml files and printing mismatch values

Tags: python, pandas, printing, yaml, diff

I have two different Yaml files. One yaml file is just slightly different to another yaml file.
I want to print two things (i.e) difference in first file when compared to second file and then difference in second file when compared to first file. Here, is my code below:-

```
import yaml
import pandas as pd
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

with open(r'C:\Users\Project\Desktop\DRsystem\stars4.yaml','r') as file:
    df1 = pd.io.json.json_normalize(yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader))

with open(r'C:\Users\Project\Desktop\DRsystem\stars5.yaml','r') as file:
    df2 = pd.io.json.json_normalize(yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader))

x = df1.to_dict()
print(x)
ddiff1 = DeepDiff(df1,df2)
print(ddiff1)
print("---------")
y = df2.to_dict()
print(y)
ddiff2 = DeepDiff(df2,df1)
print(ddiff2)
```

Output:The above code prints the difference however it displays what has been added new (i.e) anything which is not present completely in one of the yaml which is good but it does not print anything in common with a slight change. It is better understood if we can see the screenshots attached (both the yaml files along with my output attached)

query 1: why is it just printing {'root[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Morcq.jpg)': 'denmark.enabled'}} BUT not {0: True}}

query 2: canada  is present in both the files but in one file it is enabled:true and another file it is enabled:false...so why is it not showing when I am doing a diff, that it is true in one file and false in another?

[Yaml 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aHzw.jpg)

[Yaml 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcuGS.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Morcq.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> query 1: why is it just printing {'root3': 'denmark.enabled'}} BUT not
>   {0: True}}

`{0:True}` is part of the output of the pandas function `to_dict` (meaning that row `0` has the value `True`). It has nothing to do with `DeepDiff`.

> query 2: canada is present in both the files but in one file it is
>   enabled:true and another file it is enabled:false...so why is it not
>   showing when I am doing a diff, that it is true in one file and false
>   in another?

Although deepdiff [claims](https://deepdiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#deepdiff-4-3-0-documentation) to find "*differences of dictionaries, iterables, strings **and other objects***" it doesn't look deep into pandas dataframes. It just iterates over the dataframe which will yield the column headers. Hence it finds any differences in the column headers. Then it iterates over these headers - not over the values in the columns! - so it won't notice any changes in column values.

A possible workaround is to compare the dictionary representations of the dataframes:

```
print(DeepDiff(df1.to_dict(), df2.to_dict()))
```